# Apache increase concurrent connections limit not working

Tags: apache-http-server

I am running Apache and the problem I am having is that it is slow because all the workers are getting used up so I read that I needed to increase the number of workers, and I did and that helped. But I can not get the value to increase past 256, even if I set the ServerLimit like I read I am supposed to.

Here is my config:

> <IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
>
> ```
>    StartServers                     5
>
>    MinSpareServers           5
>
>    MaxSpareServers          10
>
>    MaxRequestWorkers         1000
>
>    ServerLimit     1000
>
>    MaxClients      1000
>
>    MaxConnectionsPerChild   1000
>
> </IfModule>
> ```

Here is the output from `apachectl status`:

> Apache Server Status for localhost (via ::1)
>
> Server Version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.13 OpenSSL/1.0.1f
>
> Server MPM: prefork
>
> Server Built: Jul 22 2014 14:36:38
>
> ---
>
> Current Time: Tuesday, 31-Mar-2020 20:00:18 UTC
>
> Restart Time: Tuesday, 31-Mar-2020 19:03:54 UTC
>
> Parent Server Config. Generation: 9
>
> Parent Server MPM Generation: 8
>
> Server uptime: 56 minutes 24 seconds
>
> Server load: 0.32 0.35 0.36
>   Total accesses: 48482 - Total Traffic: 1.1 GB
>   CPU Usage: u16.05 s2.1 cu0 cs0 - .536% CPU load
>   14.3 requests/sec - 344.7 kB/second - 24.1 kB/request
>   256 requests currently being processed, 0 idle workers
>
> GRGGGGRGGGGGGKRGGRGGGGGRGGGGGGGRRGRGRRRRWGRGGCGRGRGGRRGGGRGRCGGR
>
> GKGGGRGGKRKGRRRRGRGGGKRKCGRGGRRRGRGGKGGRCGGRGRGRGCRGGGRGKRRRRGRG
>
> GGGCRRRGRGGGGRRRGRGGGRGGRGRRRRGKRRRRKGRGGGGRGRRRGRRRRGGRRRKRGRRR
>
> GGGGGRRGGRGRGKGKKGGGRGRRRRGGGGRGRGGRGGRGGGGGGGGRGRGRGGKRKGGRRGGG
>
> Scoreboard Key:
>
> "_" Waiting for Connection, "S" Starting up, "R" Reading Request,
>
> "W" Sending Reply, "K" Keepalive (read), "D" DNS Lookup,
>
> "C" Closing connection, "L" Logging, "G" Gracefully finishing,
>
> "I" Idle cleanup of worker, "." Open slot with no current process

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I needed to fully restart apache using

> service apache2 stop

> service apache2 start

Just reloading with

> service apache2 reload

Did not work